# Add class to body if html attribute dir="rtl"

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a site with two language (English & Arabic) ,when change language to Arabic , Attribute dir="rtl" is added to HTML `<html dir="rtl">` ...... I want add class to body in the case of langue Arabic
I use this JQ but not work :

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       if (html.dir == "rtl"){
           $('body').addClass('aa');
       else{
           $('body').removeClass('aa');
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe use this CSS selector instead of script `html[dir="rtl"] { ... } `

Comment: Yes this idea worked with me thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you intend to do something like this with that `aa` class

```
body.aa { ... }
```

As you already have the `dir="rtl"`, may I suggest you simply use that instead, like this, and avoid an unnecessary script

```
html[dir="rtl"] { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("html").attr("dir") == "rtl") {
    $('body').addClass('rtl');
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem in this way:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("html[lang=ar]").attr("dir", "rtl")
        .find("body").addClass("rtl");
});
</script>
```